# Playing games with party chat visible

Tags: xbox-one

With the old XB1 interface that has just been replaced it used to be easy to snap the party app to the side of the screen and then change focus to the game and play the game with the party app visible the whole time. This could be really useful when in a party with people whose voices you don't know because you can see the gamertag of the person talking.

With the new XB1 interface they've changed how it works and it seems that the party app is now an overlay which disappears when you are not focusing it any more.

Is there any way to have the party app visible while continuing to play the game as there was before?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that this is possible any longer. If you look at the list of all apps that can be snapped (very bottom of the new guide), Party isn't listed.

Comment: Yeah, I'd noticed that and so feared that would be the case. :( I was just hoping there was something else out there but it looks like this is the best I'll get. :(